# Failed to access firebase storage media from flutter client

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am trying to download firebase media with appropriate permission access, but getting error `[firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.` I have cross checked from firebase rules playground. Simulated read access is granted in that case. But when trying the same from flutter client its not working.

This is the Firebase Storage rule, that I am using to use to grant media access to users according to their subscription status.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {

    function isUserSubscribed(creatorId, postId){
      let monthlySub = firestore.exists(/databases/(default)/documents/us_user/$(creatorId)/subscribers/$(request.auth.uid));

      return (
        (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null && monthlySub)
      );
    }

    match /private/us_user/{creatorId}/{postId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if (isUserSubscribed(creatorId,postId));
      allow write, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }

  }
}
```

`isUserSubscribed` function is used to evaluate the user's permission to get the media file

PS : Following is the relevant details of collections and documents required to assess the situation

Request is made from client to the path `private/us_user/john_carter/c5e091ad-aaaa-429c-aaf8-3db18603a37a/e25090bcf0384d7f9094297a1c60a2f7` assuming the user is authenticated and uid is `ejao19bd1kn1baa3`.

Flutter client Function to get media data

```
getImageData(String path) async {
    try {
    User? firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      return;
    }

    print(firebaseUser.uid);
      await _firebaseStorage.ref().child(path).getData(100000000).then((data) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            imageBytes = data;
            isUnlocked = true;
          });
          print(path);
        }
      }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
        if (error is FirebaseException) {
          if (error.message == "User is not authorized to perform the desired action.") {
            if (mounted) {
              setState(() {
                isUnlocked = true;
              });
            }
          }
        }
        log(error.toString());
        log(stackTrace.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseException) {
        log("fb ::: ${e.toString()}");
      }
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Reference Documentation [Firebase Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions)

Comment: That's a pretty cool security system!  What question do you want to ask us about it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When I try to access the media, I end up getting the error "user is not authorized to perform this operation". I want to know if there's any error in the security rule itself or If there's an alternate way to test it with same conditions.

Comment: Please edit your post to include that question/problem, so others are more likely to see it too. --- The best way to test this is probably in the security rules playground, so you can set the UID to match with the information you have in Firestore.

Comment: Thanks! Security rules playground helped me to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Ooh... that's good news.  --- What was it?

Comment: getting simulated read true while testing in playground but getting [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action. when trying from client

Comment: Perfect! If you think this may be useful for folks in a similar situation going forward, it'd help if you write an answer explaining what the problem was, how you found it, and how you fixed it. If you don't think that is useful, I vote to close the question as an ephemeral problem - just to avoid having it stay open indefinitely.

Comment: Problem is only half-way solved here. While requesting from the  Flutter client, I am still getting unauthorized error